# broken curl on ubuntu... OR... gnutls_srp_allocate_client_credentials, version GNUTLS_3_4 not defined

Tags: git, openssl, curl, gnutls

I just installed ubuntu (xenial) on a box and discovered that my newly-installed git is crippled:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome.git
Cloning into 'Font-Awesome'...
git-remote-https: relocation error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl-gnutls.so.4: symbol gnutls_srp_allocate_client_credentials, version GNUTLS_3_4 not defined in file libgnutls.so.30 with link time reference
```

It's not a git problem; `curl https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome.git` gives the same "relocation error".

I was a bit surprised that widely-used tools like git and curl would be broken on installation. Package details which seem likely to be relevant:

```
libgnutls30:am 3.4.10-4ubun amd64        GNU TLS library - main runtime li
libcurl3-gnutl 7.47.0-1ubun amd64        easy-to-use client-side URL trans
```

Two questions:

1. Am I missing something on "planet Ubuntu" with respect to setting up curl or gnutls in ubuntu?
2. Is there a straightforward fix for the apparent library dysfunction?

Comment: Have you tried to fix your problem with the installation media?

Comment: @James Thanks for the suggestion. Network connectivity isn't an issue so I went ahead and, as you suggested, completely uninstalled and reinstalled git and related curl and gnutls libraries using current xenial versions. Didn't change a thing.  More web searching revealed that Ubuntu's decision to switch from OpenSSL to GnuTLS has caused problems for others as well across a variety of applications. Rather than sink more time into this, I just built git from source against the OpenSSL-based libraries and -- voila -- it worked like a charm. Thanks again for taking the time to comment.

Comment: Yeah. I'm glad you could fix it.